# Wave animation of react-liquid-gauge not working

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, material-ui, css-animations

I have installed this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-liquid-gauge package into my reactjs application and it was working fine for some time but recently the wave animation has stopped working. I changed my computer and now this issue emerged.
My nodejs version is 16.13.1.
My npm version is 8.1.2.
Installing packages with simple npm i is not possible as it gives a dependency error. So I use npm i --legacy-peer-deps or npm i --force.
I am also attaching my package.json file content so that you can see if any other package is causing this issue.

```
{
  "name": "@minimal/material-kit-react",
  "author": "minimals.cc",
  "licence": "MIT",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx ./src",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.jsx ./src"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@iconify/icons-ant-design": "^1.1.0",
    "@iconify/icons-eva": "^1.1.0",
    "@iconify/icons-ic": "^1.1.10",
    "@iconify/react": "^3.0.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.5",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.47",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.0",
    "@mui/utils": "^5.0.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.7.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "apexcharts": "^3.28.3",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "change-case": "^4.1.2",
    "d3-color": "^3.0.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.24.0",
    "faker": "^5.5.3",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "history": "^5.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.9",
    "react-d3-cloud": "^1.0.5",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-drop-zone": "^4.3.2",
    "react-helmet-async": "^1.1.2",
    "react-liquid-gauge": "^1.2.4",
    "react-notifications-component": "^3.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.4",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "simplebar": "^5.3.5",
    "simplebar-react": "^2.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.5",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.15.7",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

here is my component

import

```
 * as React from 'react';
import { color } from 'd3-color';
import LiquidFillGauge from 'react-liquid-gauge';

export default function LiquidTank() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(50);

  const radius = 200;
  const fillColor = '#dc143c';
  const gradientStops = [
    {
      key: '0%',
      stopColor: color(fillColor).darker(0.5).toString(),
      stopOpacity: 1,
      offset: '0%'
    },
    {
      key: '50%',
      stopColor: fillColor,
      stopOpacity: 0.75,
      offset: '50%'
    },
    {
      key: '100%',
      stopColor: color(fillColor).brighter(0.5).toString(),
      stopOpacity: 0.5,
      offset: '100%'
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div
      className="position-relative"
      style={{
        maxWidth: '317px'
      }}
    >
      <LiquidFillGauge
        style={{ margin: '0 auto' }}
        width={radius * 2}
        height={radius * 2}
        value={value}
        percent="%"
        textSize={1}
        textOffsetX={0}
        textOffsetY={0}
        textRenderer={(props) => {
          const value = Math.round(props.value);
          const radius = Math.min(props.height / 2, props.width / 2);
          const textPixels = (props.textSize * radius) / 2;
          const valueStyle = {
            fontSize: textPixels
          };
          const percentStyle = {
            fontSize: textPixels * 0.6
          };

          return (
            <tspan>
              <tspan className="value" style={valueStyle}>
                {value}
              </tspan>
              <tspan style={percentStyle}>{props.percent}</tspan>
            </tspan>
          );
        }}
        riseAnimation
        waveAnimation
        waveFrequency={2}
        waveAmplitude={1}
        gradient
        gradientStops={gradientStops}
        circleStyle={{
          fill: fillColor
        }}
        waveStyle={{
          fill: fillColor
        }}
        textStyle={{
          fill: color('#444').toString(),
          fontFamily: 'Arial'
        }}
        waveTextStyle={{
          fill: color('#fff').toString(),
          fontFamily: 'Arial'
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine. [Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-liquid-gauge-cfhgg5?file=/src/index.js) What's the dependency error you get?

Comment: @Shreshth thanks for your reply. Yes, it is working in the code sandbox and I have also tried to change the nodejs version and add all the dependencies in the code box to break it but it is still working. Don't know what's wrong with my project. I will try to create another project and add all the components one by one to see where the problem is.

Comment: Right. Hard to say without looking at it, maybe also try to get rid of dependencies you might not be using in code.

Comment: I am posting the solution here so that if anybody stumbles here in the future. The problem is with the "d3-color" package as I am trying to install it by npm. Just uninstall it and react-liquid-gauge too and then run this command npm install --save react-liquid-gauge. I know this can be silly but it took me days to solve this issue. A lot of time to waste especially we you need to deliver things :).